# How to interpret this class of numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let's say $ f(p) $ is a number defined as shown below:

$ \hspace {10 mm}f(p) = {\sqrt {2} ^ {{\sqrt {2} ^ \sqrt {2}} ^ {... \hspace {1 mm} p\hspace {1 mm} times } }} $

What I understand is: 
We normally assume, presume or impose a restriction on $p$ that $p$ should be a positive integer.


My question is: 
**Can we allow $p$ to be any number in general?**

```
      e.g. Can $p$ be irrational?
```

If *yes*, how to interpret such a number?

If *no*, why?

Thanks.

Comment: At this time there is no commonly accepted solution to the general problem of extending tetration to the real or complex values of n. Various approaches are mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_real_heights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As suggested in meta, I'll turn my comment into an answer (CW).*

At this time there is no commonly accepted solution to the general problem of extending tetration to the real or complex values of n. Various approaches are mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_real_heights .

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer of Harun Siljak one should perhaps mention that for the slightly different expression
$$ \operatorname{dxp}\small([topexponent],[base],[iterationheight])=\operatorname{dxp}(x,t,h) $$
where
$$     \operatorname{dxp}(x,t,0)= x \\\ 
   \operatorname{dxp}(x,t,1)= t^x - 1 \\\ 
    \operatorname{dxp}(x,t,2)= t^{t^x - 1 } - 1 \\\
   \cdots
 $$
there is a solution for real $h$ based on the power series for the exponential function minus the constant term. Usually this is discussed for the function $$    \operatorname{dxp}(x,e,1)= \exp(x) - 1  $$ and fractional or even irrational  heights $h$ and a parametrization for the coefficients for
$$    \operatorname{dxp}(x,t,1)=  \sum_{k=1}^\infty u^k{x^k \over k!}  \\\
     \operatorname{dxp}(x,t,h)=  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal{P}(u,h,k){x^k \over k!}  \\\
   \text{where I wrote }u \text{ for } \ln(t)
$$ where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes a polynomial in iteration-height, $\ln(t)$ and the series-index $k$.

For series like this and its iterations it is accepted, that the indicated family of iteration heights form a semigroup, where the height-parameter $h$ can be non-integer and can even be complex. This can already be found in L.Comtet's "advanced combinatorics" but also elsewhere.

Unfortunately, although the iterations of *dxp()* and *exp()* can be converted into each other (simply by a change of base) for integer heights, this is not uniquely determined for the fractional heights (the reason is, that for the same base in $b^x$ we have multiple bases $t$ in $t^x-1$ and the various $t$ give different results for the same $x$ and height $h$ if $h$ is fractional). Which then leads to the comment in the other answer, that there is not (yet) a commonly accepted interpretation for the noninteger heights in your original problem.